# Local Path not found with Java Library Android Studio 1.0.1

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have seen that having the Local path not found bug is quite a common one to have with Android studio. There are a couple of examples of it here on stack overflow([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294663/cannot-build-android-project-using-android-studio-gradle-1-7)). However, my case is unique in that mine is not caused by adding the support libraries twice or malformed xml. I know this as I can remove all references to my Java library project and it will work and run on my device. However, as soon as I uncomment the lines of code and add my java library as a dependency I receive errors again.

I have a theory why I am receiving this error but I would love to hear everyone else's views or better yet, a solution!
Below is my project structure:
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkxDQ.png]

but perhaps more importantly this is the libs folder of the Osmosis folder:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9tSa.png]

As you can see, this project depends on a lot of files. When I run the project, I recieve the following error.:

Gradle console:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.6.2/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --output /Volumes/default/My stuff/Developer/android studio/WindowRunner/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/osmosis-68e393234faceebfb2923624b3ad140c0ee95f84.jar /Volumes/default/My stuff/Developer/android studio/WindowRunner/osmosis/build/libs/osmosis.jar
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    ...while parsing common/MyNode.class

    1 error; aborting


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED



Total time: 4.38 secs
```

ADB:

```
    Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-nexus_5-095034570b96f962
Uploading file
    local path: /Volumes/default/My stuff/Developer/android studio/WindowRunner/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.mattboyle.windowrunner
Local path doesn't exist.
```

This line I think is causing the issue:

```
Failed to run command:
        /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.6.2/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --output /Volumes/default/My stuff/Developer/android studio/WindowRunner/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/osmosis-68e393234faceebfb2923624b3ad140c0ee95f84.jar /Volumes/default/My stuff/Developer/android studio/WindowRunner/osmosis/build/libs/osmosis.jar
```

As there is no such thing in my library as osmosis.jar?

I'm not sure what the dex stage of build does but would love some advice on how to fix this.

Settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':osmosis'
```

build.gradle (main)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mattboyle.windowrunner"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile project(':osmosis')
}
```

build.gradle(osmosis)

```
    apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for adding the images- I don't have enough rep(I'm close!) to do it.

Comment: That library is not designed for use on Android. Besides being huge and using third-party JARs that themselves are not designed for use on Android, the documentation cites the use of `java.awt.geom` classes that do not exist on Android.

Comment: Please could you point me to the documentation? As i understood it android was a subset of java so any java jars should be compilable

Comment: "Please could you point me to the documentation?" -- I was looking at [this OSM Wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis). "so any java jars should be compilable" -- they will neither compile from source nor run as a binary if they refer to things that do not exist in Android. Java is a language, not a class library. Android's class library is not Java SE, or Java EE, or Java ME, but rather its own. It is closest to Java SE, but there are *lots* of things in Java SE that do not exist in Android.

Comment: So using this project as a library is impossible?

Comment: Probably not without modification. I believe OSM has their own support channels; you might consider inquiring there as to whether or not anyone has recently gotten `osmosis` working on Android. I saw one post that indicated that a modified version of `osmosis` from three years ago worked.