# Gradle throw app:mergedebugresources exception

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This project previously from intellij, now migrate to android studio as Gradle android project. 
I wish to add google play service dependency using gradle later, I can't find specific jar elsewhere... 
Previously this project was running fine using ant, after import as gradle in android studio, I get Gradle mergedebugresources exception.

I tried to rebuild project, sync project with gradle file, but didn't work for me... Am I missing something?

Hope someone guide me, I'm new to Gradle & android studio.

> Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>   Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources
>   Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>   :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>     Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> - Try:
>     Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is:
>     org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
>     at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
>     at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
>     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>     at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:161)
>     at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:88)
>     at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>     ... 70 more
>     Caused by: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>     at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:268)
>     at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:301)
>     at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:410)
>     at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:154)
>     ... 78 more
>     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
>     at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:264)
>     ... 81 more
>     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
>     at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.lambda$compile$0(AaptV1.java:446)
>     Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>     at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.out(AaptProcess.java:284)
>     at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.out(AaptProcess.java:215)
>     at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$2.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:143)
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2.273 secs

My project file structure like:

[image: a busy cat]

Appreciate any suggestions or guidance.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check the suggestions given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294663/cannot-build-android-project-using-android-studio-gradle-1-7).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry to update my answer. 
Found out actually is 9 patch image with error format, one 9 patch image didn't proper draw the black corner line in the most outer. 
My careless mistake! Really using photoshop not proper to make 9 patch image!
Previous ant project didn't notice this issue.

Now with Gradle that give proper check and throws exception. 
However, the log message really not helpful for debug!

Comment: "changed all .jpg to .png"? But you say "cannot have any .png". But, it actually can have PNG files. It also can have JPG files. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: Yes, I post this question I already changed jpg to png in my drawable folder, I got revert back to previous backup project, and tested multiple times.

Comment: Solve this when I move png & jpg to other drawable-hdpi & other folders, left drawable empty

Comment: I just don't think moving the drawables or renaming necessarily fixed the issue, that's all

Comment: Not so sure, in my case that how I solve this mergeDebugResources error...

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem, using Android Studio 2.2.3.

But I get this error after importing my project into a CVS repository.
I tried this with a new empty dummy project.

What I found so far

- PNG files are treated as text files per default (0d, 0a conversion) and are garbage when checking out again, tried this with a new project with one PNG file inside, so never import a new project with existing PNGs, add them after the first import to be able to specify their type.
- The merger.xml file in \build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources is deleted after CVS import. Even if I copy the original merger.xml into the folder, the build doesn't work too. After initiating the build the merger.xml files is deleted again.

Hey what's going on here, with an IDE version 2.2.3 there should not be such elemental problems?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem occurred by the **path** of my `GRADLE_HOME` which **contained non-English character** ("ó") and which is the user home directory/.gradle by default. The solution was to change Gradle's Service directory path in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle so that it doesn't contain non-English characters, like this:

[Gradle setting that caused the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSrkS.png)