# Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'mergeDebugResources'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Does anyone ever encountered this problem?

This is my error and I have no idea what to do.

```
Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'mergeDebugResources' 
property 'outputDir' during up-to-date check
>Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\<Username>\AndroidStudioProjects\MainActivity\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml'
```

btw I'm only new to Android Studio, so please go easy on me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: when does that happen? could you be more specific?
what gradle version are you running?

Comment: My gradle version is 3.3. And it displays when I run the project.

Comment: have you tried Android Studio> Build> Clean Project  ?
Or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20549266/2928241 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/17484967/2928241 ?